# Applying two xsl templates alternately

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two node sets, one with names and one with images. I am looking for a way to apply/call templates so that the entries are grouped in this way: X images, 8 persons, 8 persons, Y images, Z images, 8 persons, 8 persons,… If there are no images left, persons need to be output. It's always 8 persons per group but I'd like to have different numbers of images per group.

The intended result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hzuM.png

My xml input is simple:

```
<persons>
   <entry>person 1</entry>
   <entry>person 2</entry>
   <entry>person 3</entry>
   <entry>person 4</entry>
   <entry>person 5</entry>
   <entry>…</entry>
   <entry>person 74</entry>
</persons>
<images>
   <entry>image 1</entry>
   <entry>image 2</entry>
   <entry>image 3</entry>
   <entry>image 4</entry>
   <entry>image 5</entry>
   <entry>…</entry>
   <entry>image 13</entry>
</images>
```

The output needs to look like this:

```
<!--Not part of the loop-->
<div class="imageGroup left">
   <img src="image1" class="imageGroup2-1">
   <img src="image2" class="imageGroup2-2">
</div>

<!--Start of the loop-->
<div class="personGroup right">
   <div class="person">person 1</div>
   <div class="person">person 2</div>
   <div class="person">person 3</div>
   <div class="person">person 4</div>
   <div class="person">person 5</div>
   <div class="person">person 6</div>
   <div class="person">person 7</div>
   <div class="person">person 8</div>
</div>
<div class="personGroup left">
   <div class="person">person 9</div>
   <div class="person">person 10</div>
   <div class="person">person 11</div>
   <div class="person">person 12</div>
   <div class="person">person 13</div>
   <div class="person">person 14</div>
   <div class="person">person 15</div>
   <div class="person">person 16</div>
</div>
<div class="imageGroup right">
   <img src="image3" class="imageGroup2-1">
   <img src="image4" class="imageGroup2-2">
</div>
<div class="imageGroup left">
   <img src="image5" class="imageGroup3-1">
   <img src="image6" class="imageGroup3-2">
   <img src="image7" class="imageGroup3-2">
</div>
<div class="personGroup right">
   <div class="person">person 17</div>
   <div class="person">person 18</div>
   <div class="person">person 19</div>
   <div class="person">person 20</div>
   <div class="person">person 21</div>
   <div class="person">person 22</div>
   <div class="person">person 23</div>
   <div class="person">person 24</div>
</div>
<div class="personGroup left">
   <div class="person">person 25</div>
   <div class="person">person 26</div>
   <div class="person">person 27</div>
   <div class="person">person 28</div>
   <div class="person">person 29</div>
   <div class="person">person 30</div>
   <div class="person">person 31</div>
   <div class="person">person 32</div>
</div>
<div class="imageGroup right">
   <img src="image8" class="imageGroup3-1">
   <img src="image9" class="imageGroup3-2">
   <img src="image10" class="imageGroup3-3">
</div>
<div class="imageGroup left">
   <img src="image11" class="imageGroup2-1">
   <img src="image12" class="imageGroup2-2">
</div>
<--End of the loop-->

<!--Next loop-->
<div class="personGroup right">
   <div class="person">person 33</div>
   <div class="person">person 34</div>
   <div class="person">person 35</div>
   <div class="person">person 36</div>
   <div class="person">person 37</div>
   <div class="person">person 38</div>
   <div class="person">person 39</div>
   <div class="person">person 40</div>
</div>
<div class="personGroup left">
   <div class="person">person 41</div>
   <div class="person">person 42</div>
   <div class="person">person 43</div>
   <div class="person">person 44</div>
   <div class="person">person 45</div>
   <div class="person">person 46</div>
   <div class="person">person 47</div>
   <div class="person">person 48</div>
</div>
<!--Only one image left over, class name is 2-x anyway-->
<div class="imageGroup right">
   <img src="image13" class="imageGroup2-1">
</div>
<!--As no images are left, the next group is a person group-->
<div class="personGroup left">
   <div class="person">person 49</div>
   <div class="person">person 50</div>
   <div class="person">person 60</div>
   <div class="person">person 70</div>
   <div class="person">person 71</div>
   <div class="person">person 72</div>
   <div class="person">person 73</div>
   <div class="person">person 74</div>
</div>
```

Rules for the transformation:

- The output is arranged in groups. Every odd group has the "class" left, every even group the class "right".
- The first group contains 2 images. The first group is an exemption.
- The following pattern is beaing repeated:
- two groups of persons
- a group with 2 images and a group with 3 images
- two groups of persons
- a group with 3 images and a group with 2 images
- (End of repetition)
- Each image has a class that tells how many images the group has and which position the image has within the group ("imageGroup3-2" means group with 3 images, this image is at position 2 witihn the group).
- Should the image nodeset run empty, the last image group may contain less images. After this only groups of persons will be added.
- It won't be the case that the persons nodeset runs empty before the image nodeset.

How do do this? A combination of apply-templates and within a call-template? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am afraid your question isn't clear at all. Please post your expected result **as code**. Make sure we understand what goes where from input to output (you'll probably want to use a larger data group as the input example).

Comment: Okay, I *think* I understand how the persons need to be divided into groups of 16 each, with each subgroup of 8 facing the opposite direction. But I still can't see the logic by which the images are interspersed between those groups.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for following my thoughts. The images are interspersed for layout reasons. This [image](http://i.imgur.com/YjGOv2B.png) shows the layout I am aiming for: a group of images and a group of 8 persons are in one row (left, right), then the next two groups follow in the next row.

Comment: I am sorry, but we need some **rules** here.

Comment: I hope I get right what you mean with rules. I give it a try, I'll add them to my question.

Comment: By *rules* I mean this: imagine you are giving this task to a very stupid but reliable person to do manually. He'll do **exactly** what you tell him to do, step by step. Now just write out the steps he needs to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously going to take some work, but let me suggest the following as the starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="data/persons/entry[position() mod 32 = 1]" >
        <xsl:variable name="group" select="floor(count(preceding-sibling::entry) div 32)" />
        <xsl:variable name="persons" select=". | following-sibling::entry" />
        <xsl:variable name="images" select="/data/images/entry[position() > 10*$group]" />

        <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="$group"/></xsl:comment>
            <!-- 2 images, left -->
            <div class="imageGroup left">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$images[position() &lt;= 2]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="imageGroup" select="2"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </div>

            <!-- 8 persons, right -->
            <div class="personGroup right">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$persons[position() &lt;= 8]"/>
            </div>
            <!-- 8 persons, left -->
            <div class="personGroup left">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$persons[8 &lt; position() and position() &lt;= 16]"/>
            </div>

            <!-- 2 images, right -->
            <div class="imageGroup right">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$images[2 &lt; position() and position() &lt;= 4]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="imageGroup" select="2"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </div>
            <!-- 3 images, left -->
            <div class="imageGroup left">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$images[4 &lt; position() and position() &lt;= 7]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="imageGroup" select="3"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </div>

            <!-- 8 persons, right -->
            <div class="personGroup right">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$persons[16 &lt; position() and position() &lt;= 24]"/>
            </div>
            <!-- 8 persons, left -->
            <div class="personGroup left">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$persons[24 &lt; position() and position() &lt;= 32]"/>
            </div>

            <!-- 3 images, right -->
            <div class="imageGroup right">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$images[7 &lt; position() and position() &lt;= 10]">
                    <xsl:with-param name="imageGroup" select="3"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="persons/entry">
    <div class="person"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="images/entry">
    <xsl:param name="imageGroup"/>
    <img src="{.}" class="imageGroup{$imageGroup}-{position()}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action here: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLZ/1

Comment: This is very near. Thanks for your time and help (and for teaching me how to ask better). Only three changes are necessary to make the answer complete: A) The first image group should be an exemption and not part of the loop, the loop starts after it. B) The loop then needs one more image group at its end. C) Empty groups must not be output and omitting an empty group must not break the alternation of left/right (see update of the question).

Comment: @Moritz I believe the first two changes cancel each other. Empty groups can be prevented by wrapping the `<div>` in an `<xsl:if>` statement checking if there are enough images/persons to start the group. The last requirement is more problematic, and may require processing in two passes.

Comment: Thanks so far. Please allow me some time to try this out.